# How do I resize the Safari browser window

Tags: windows-7, safari

I'm trying to resize my Safari browser to be a specific height/width. In Firefox I use the Web Developer Toolbar, and in IE I user their developer tools.

How do I do this in Safari? I've already enabled the developer tools, but I don't see a resize option.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with Javascript. Simply type something like this into the address bar.

```
javascript:self.resizeTo(800,600);
```

A couple of things though. This will resize the inner frame of the window, so the entire window including borders and toolbars will be larger. Also, this seems to work only on windows with a single tab, and I only tried it on a Mac, would think it behaves the same on other platforms thou.

Comment: This works, but is not an ideal solution. I'd like to have an iPad and iPhone (amongst others)  resolution saved.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the response above me because of it's simplicity.
There are, however some resizing plugins, both free and paid:

[Resizer](http://sixfoot1.com/safari-extensions/resizer/) (free afaik)

[Resize](http://resizesafari.com/) ($29)